# Problema al subir un fichero con ruby a SAP con un RFC

Tags: ruby

Estoy intentando subir a SAP de forma automática ciertos ficheros mediante un RFC creado para tal fin. Si utilizo el RFC desde la aplicación, funciona correctamente pero al intentarlo desde la aplicación ruby, a la hora de meter los ficheros en la tabla correspondiente la aplicación falla. Hasta ese punto, todo es correcto (marcado en el código siguiente con un comentario)

Alguna idea de porqué puede ser? No sé si tendrá algo que ver con permisos, porque SAP pide confirmación al hacerlo desde su entorno y me sorprendería que sea capaz de cargar los ficheros con solo darle la ruta.

Solo se muestra el siguiente error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application
>   owner check the logs for more information.

Código Ruby:

```
def upload
  parametros = Hash.new
  parametros["user"] = "xxx"
  parametros["passwd"] = "xxx"
  parametros["client"] = "xxx"
  parametros["ashost"] = "sapservertest.xxxx.es"
  parametros["sysnr"] = "xxx"

  c = NWRFC::Connection.new(parametros)

  @info = c.connection_info 
  @function = c.get_function("ZRFC_PLM_CREAR_DOC_INFO_ING")
  @call = @function.get_function_call
  @metodos = @function.methods
  @call_metodos = @call.methods

  @call['I_DOKNR'] = 'xxx'
  @call['I_DOKVR'] = '00'
  @call['I_DKTXT'] = 'Prueba xx'
  @call['I_RESP'] = 'xxx'
  @call['I_PAQ_PROD'] = 'ESP'
  @call['I_OBJ_PROD'] = 'MPL'
  @call['I_RELEV_COMPR'] = 'NO'
  @call['I_DOC_ENTREG'] = 'NO'
  @call['I_CLASIF_SEG'] = 'CONF'
  @call['I_DENOM_IDIOMA'] = 'ES'

  @call['IT_ENLACES'].new_row { |r|
    r['TIP_ENLACE'] = 'xxx'
    r['OBJ_ENLACE'] = 'xxx'
  }

  @call['IT_ENLACES'].new_row { |r|
    r['TIP_ENLACE'] = 'xxx'
    r['OBJ_ENLACE'] = 'T-xxx'
  }

  #---------------HASTA AQUI FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE

  @call['IT_FILES'].new_row { |r|
    r['RUTA'] = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\ejemplo.html'
  }

  @call.invoke
end
```

Estoy utilizando la gema *nwrfc* para ello, no he encontrado nada más actual.

Gracias de antemano,

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el _log_ completo del error?

Comment: No hay más error, solo se muestra eso. No tengo acceso a los log de SAP